# Solr/Tika dataimport temporary files permission exception

Tags: linux, solr, apache-tika, temporary-files, data-importer

I'm trying to setup data import from files using apache tika and solr. There are shared docs folder on nfs mounted share. Unfortunately, I can't perform dataimport, 1 file processed and then exception:

```
[http-8080-3] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder - Exception while processing: files document : null:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to read content Processing Document # 2
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Access denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1989)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TemporaryResources.createTemporaryFile(TemporaryResources.java:66)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream.getFile(TikaInputStream.java:533)
    at org.apache.tika.io.TikaInputStream.getFileChannel(TikaInputStream.java:564)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.getTopLevelNames(POIFSContainerDetector.java:373)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.POIFSContainerDetector.detect(POIFSContainerDetector.java:165)
    at org.apache.tika.detect.CompositeDetector.detect(CompositeDetector.java:61)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor.nextRow(TikaEntityProcessor.java:140)
    ... 26 more
```

So it seems to be some problem with permissions while writing temporary files. Unfortunately, I have no idea where exactly tike tries to write that temporary files so I can't check permissions on nfs. I checked permission for tika home folder (core configuration) and docs folder and subfolders - all ok, including problematic document.

I also tried to change docs directory in my core config to other (on the same nfs share) and all is ok. So, do you have any idea how to track my issue?

[EDIT]
I just noticed that it's not really permission problem. Everything works for files .docx and .pdf. But on .doc file it fails. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It should be using the System Default temp directory, which on Linux is typically `/tmp/`. What happens if you set the `java.io.tmpdir` JVM property to be a directory you do have write permissions to?

Comment: Where should I set this? Also note that only doc files causes problems. All the rest (.docx, .pdf) are indexed just fine. So it's really weird.

Comment: So file formats can be converted to plain text without needing temp files when starting from an input stream, but not all. The right way of passing that property to the JVM depends on how you start the JVM...

Comment: Ok, I set -Djava.io.tmpdir for tomcat (in /usr/sbin/tomcat6) directly to /tmp, then restarted tomcat. User tomcat has permissions to /tmp (I can login to tomcat account and touch file in /tmp). But my issue still exists

Comment: Do you have anything like selinux in place which might restrict things? Your problem is that at runtime, the JVM doesn't have the right permissions to create the temp file...

Comment: I tried setenforce Permissive, but no change. Also tested on other machine with selinux completly disabled (but I didn't set -Djava.io to /tmp directly there yet)

Comment: OK I completly disabled selinux for testing. Still the same, any ideas?